# Retrieve information of a deleted user in Azure AD using graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there any way to retrieve information on a deleted user in Azure AD using Graph API?

I need the deleted date of that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user` endpoint.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user?$select=id,deletedDateTime,displayName
```

`deletedDateTime` is not returned by default, so it must be specified in the `$select`.

Users are permanently deleted automatically 30 days after they are deleted. The endpoint will return only users deleted in last 30 days.

Resource:

[List deleted items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks for the help !! can we able to select only these three items (id,deletedDateTime,displayName)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

GET /directory/deletedItems/microsoft.graph.user

But if it is hard deletion, I don't think you can retrieve the information